# Write HTML data to NSPasteboard

Tags: html, objective-c, macos, cocoa, nspasteboard

I am trying to copy an html data to clipboard on MAC. But when i check the clipboard using (Finder-> Edit Menu -> Show clipboard) it shows nothing. I want the formatted data to be pasted as it is. Below is the code i am using:

```
NSPasteboard *pb = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
NSAttributedString *htmlString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"<html><body><b>abcdefgh</b></body></html>"];
NSDictionary *documentAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute, nil];
NSData *htmlData = [htmlString dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, htmlString.length) documentAttributes:documentAttributes error:NULL];

[pb declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSHTMLPboardType] owner:nil];
[pb setData:htmlData forType:NSHTMLPboardType];
```

I will appreciate any help. Thanks!

Update:

To get the html formatted string in clipboard, i tried converting it to Attributed string and then from attributed string to rtf data, it sets the data to clip board perfectly, but when i try to paste the data in html editor  ( http://htmleditor.in/ ) it loses some formatting like colour.

```
 NSPasteboard *pb = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
 NSString *htmlString = @"<HTML> <BODY> <P><FONT COLOR=\"RED\"><UL><LI>fhhj</LI><LI>juil</LI></UL><B>hello</B> <i>html</i></FONT></P> </BODY></HTML>";

NSDictionary *documentAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute,[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding], nil];

NSAttributedString* atr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:documentAttributes documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

 NSData *rtf = [atr RTFFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, [atr length])
                                    documentAttributes:nil];

    [pb declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSRTFPboardType] owner:nil];
    [pb setData:rtf forType:NSRTFPboardType];
```

How to preserve color when pasting to html editor? Text is shown with color on clipboard then why it isn't pasted with color on html editor (http://htmleditor.in/)?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the issue, the functionality is browser dependent(i don't understand the reason though).
If i paste to the site in safari, it doesn't lose any formatting and works well, but if i paste the same text to same site on chrome, it loses some formatting.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**

If you want it copied with the attributes applied, then use

```
NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:@"YOUR HTML CODE" documentAttributes:NULL];
[pb setData:attrString forType: NSPasteboardTypeRTF];
```

Comment: And then use `[pb setString:htmlString forType:NSStringPboardType];`

Comment: @Julian I think OP wants it copied as html data, so `NSPasteboardTypeHTML` would be fine (`NSHTMLPboardType` is deprecated).

Comment: Sounds obvous... But does it make a big difference? Or does it make a difference for any kind of receiver?

Comment: As far as I know they are the same, it just allows the receiver of the pasteboard to know whether or not it contains HTML data.

Comment: I want the string to be pasted as formatted string, this will paste the entire html.. i want abcdefgh to be pasted in bold

Comment: Than you should use `<b>abcdefgh</b>` because HTML is not bold. Or don't use NSPasteboardTypeHTML but string instead... Am I right?

Comment: Its already there in html string... @"<html><body><b>abcdefgh</b></body></html>"

Comment: No, you're initializing it as `NSAttributedString`. That's different from `NSString`

Comment: @Neha then that's something entirely different, I'll make a quick edit.

Comment: initWithHTML takes NSData and setData also takes NSData

Comment: Didn't read which class initWithHTML took my bad. In that case it seems like a formatting issue with the website. Are you sure with the same method, copying html data from somewhere else and pasted to that website it gives the accurate results?

Comment: Thanks for your help, i finally got the reason of issue.